# Looking for a web scraper tool to extract entire table out of web pages and put them in different sheets in excel

Tags: web-scraping, excelquery

The first column of this table contains all the links I have to work with: https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/DRCCStudySummary.php?Mode=StudySummary&SortBy=Analysis&AscDesc=asc&ResultsPerPage=2000

From each of the links I have to download entire tables like this: https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/show_metabolites_by_study.php?STUDY_ID=ST000886&SORTFIELD=moverz_quant

and put each of the table from each of the links into separate sheets in excel.

I'd highly appreciate if anyone could tell me how to automate the entire process.

P.S.: I can't code...

Answer (score 0):

ParseHub is  a tool that is free and powerful web scraper to scrape data from tables.
I have used it in the past by following [this step by step description](https://www.parsehub.com/blog/web-scrape-table/):

NO CODING NEEDED.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. ParseHub is amazing. Takes a while to wrap hear around but you get it it's an amazing tool to have.